# Not sure why I can't match this regex in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to match the string "September 12" with the following C# code.  But it won't match and I'm not sure why.  What am I doing wrong? It appears to work on regexpal.com

```
public static void Scan(String str)
    {
        String digits = "(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)";

        String r1 = "September " + digits + "+";

        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(str, r1, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace))
        {
            String value = match.Value;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the flag RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace. Remove it since you don't want to ignore whitespace in the regular expression - you need it to match the whitespace between "September" and "19".

Hint: `digits` can be written more easy as [0-9]. A better regular expression would be

```
September [0-9]+
```

Comment: Yip this is the actual reason. Hint [0-9]+ can also be \d+

Comment: Also you can use `\ ` (there is a space after that slash).

Answer (score 2):

As @Moritz pointed out your are not matching because you are Ignoring Whitespace.  You should also note that your current method will match a wide range of "dates" that are invalid.  `September 67` for instance.

I would recommend using a slightly more complex pattern for matching the number pattern:

```
September ([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

This will limit the numbers to between 1 and 31.  While this will still allow some invalid dates (`September 31` for instance) it will greatly limit the number of invalid dates matched.

Comment: I would also add a possible zero before the single digit numbers: ``(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])``

Answer (score 0):

@"September\s\d+" should do it

The \s matches a space, the \d matches any digit, and the + is 1 or more of the preceding.

Comment: `\s` matches any whitespace character, even tab etc. He just wants a single space, which is `\ `.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it this way.

```
public static void Scan(String str)
{
  // This regex is pretty nasty, I would probably take more time to refine it.
  String patt = @"^([A-Za-z]+)(\s)(\d+)$";

  foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(str, patt, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace))
  {
    String value = match.Value;

    Console.WriteLine(value);
  }
}
```

...

Then call it like:

```
Scan("September 2011");
```